# Error with syntax of Overpass API and Overpy

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

this is my code to access overpy and the Overpass API. I need every street in a city. The replace functions are not nice, but the should work because I need the double curly brackets and I can't use then if I simply write them. But my problem is something different. If I run this code on the Overpass API Website it works just fine. But if I send the following, I get this error from Overpy:

```
overpy.exception.OverpassBadRequest: Error: line 3: parse error: Unknown type &quot;{&quot;
Error: line 3: parse error: An empty query is not allowed
Error: line 3: parse error: ';' expected - '{' found.
```

Does anyone know, where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance!

```
import overpy

def fetchAPI():
    api = overpy.Overpass()

    # fetch all streets in city
    value = '''
        [out:json];
        §$geocodeArea:"Berlin, Deutschland"%&->.searchArea;
        way["highway"]["name"](area.searchArea);
        out;
    '''.replace('§', '{').replace('$', '{').replace('%', '}').replace('&', '}')
    print(value)
    result = api.query(value)
    #get from the result the first way and print the name
    print(len(result.ways))
    #for i in range(len(result.ways)):
        #print(result.ways[i].tags.get("name"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fetchAPI()
```

Comment: Take a look at the HTTP request you are sending to Overpass API. Something is wrong with the query in the request.

Answer (score 0):

`geocodeArea` is an overpass turbo specific extension, as described in the [OpenStreetMap wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Extended_Overpass_Turbo_Queries). This extension is only available in your browser as Javascript code.

Since you're sending your query directly to the Overpass API backend service, you're bypassing this frontend code, and the backend complains about invalid Overpass QL syntax. This is totally expected, and means that you would have to implement something similar to `geocodeArea` in your Python code.